# Building a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have such a base structure (short version)

**Table Product:**

```
product_id, name, status 
1, Product 1, 1
2, Product 2, 1
3, Product 3, 1 
4, Product 4, 1
99, Product 99, 1
```

**Table Box:**

```
box_id, name 
1, Box 1
```

**Table Product_To_Box:**

```
box_id, product_id 
1, 1 
1, 2 
1, 3 
1, 4 
1, 99
```

**Table Url:** (id = product_id from the table 'product')

```
url_id, id, url, language_id 
1, 1, wp.pl, 1 
2, 1, wp.pl, 2 
3, 2, google.pl, 1
```

**Table Language:**

```
language_id, name 
1, English 
2, Polish
```

There is no problem when I need to download all the products from the table 'product', which is not present in table 'url' and are assigned a 'box_id'. 
I do this query

```
SELECT p.product_id AS id FROM product p LEFT JOIN product_to_box p2b ON (p.product_id = p2b.product_id) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT u.id FROM url u WHERE p.product_id = u.id) AND p2b.box_id = '1'
```

**Return 3 products:**

```
Product 3 
Product 4 
Product 99
```

However, he needs a query that will return the items as above but additionally also the products that have no connection to each language from the table 'language'

**Query should return 4 products:**

```
Product 2 - return the product because the table 'url' no entry for language_id = 2 
Product 3 
Product 4 
Product 99
```

How would add another language to the table 'language', eg. Vietnam (language_id = 3) and Table 'url' would look like this

```
1, 1, wp.pl, 1 
2, 1, wp.pl, 2 
3, 2, google.pl, 1 
3, 2, google.pl, 2 
3, 3, google.com, 1 
3, 3, google.com, 2 
3, 4, onet.pl, 1 
3, 4, onet.pl, 2 
3, 99, interia.pl, 1 
3, 99, interia.pl, 2
```

This query should return all products because the table 'url' there is no reference to language_id = 3

```
Product 1 
Product 2 
Product 3 
Product 4 
Product 99
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think the problem with you query is the sub query "NOT EXISTS (SELECT u.id FROM url u WHERE p.product_id = u.id)".  Currently your SQL query doesn't even look at the language table, so it doesn't matter if there is matching language_ids.  However, if you want join all the tables together and show all product_to_box.id = 1 then the following query would work:

```
SELECT p.product_id AS id, url_id, url, l.name FROM product p LEFT JOIN product_to_box p2b ON (p.product_id = p2b.product_id) 
 LEFT JOIN url ON (p.product_id = url.id) LEFT JOIN language l ON (url.language_id = l.language_id)
 WHERE p2b.box_id = '1';

This outputs the following:
+------+--------+-----------+---------+
| id   | url_id | url       | name    |
+------+--------+-----------+---------+
|    1 |      1 | wp.pl     | English |
|    1 |      2 | wp.pl     | Polish  |
|    2 |      3 | google.pl | English |
|    3 |   NULL | NULL      | NULL    |
|    4 |   NULL | NULL      | NULL    |
|   99 |   NULL | NULL      | NULL    |
+------+--------+-----------+---------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The below SQL will show all product_id from the table 'product', that is not found in the table 'url' and do not have assigned all language_id from table 'language'.  It checks to see if url.id or language_id is null.

```
SELECT p.product_id AS id, url_id, url, l.name FROM product p LEFT JOIN product_to_box p2b ON (p.product_id = p2b.product_id) 
 LEFT JOIN url ON (p.product_id = url.id) LEFT JOIN language l ON (url.language_id = l.language_id)
 WHERE url.id is null or l.language_id is null;

+------+--------+------+------+
| id   | url_id | url  | name |
+------+--------+------+------+
|    3 |   NULL | NULL | NULL |
|    4 |   NULL | NULL | NULL |
|   99 |   NULL | NULL | NULL |
+------+--------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I need to show all product_id from the table 'product', that is not found in the table 'url' and do not have assigned all language_id from table 'language'.

Comment: Thank you for help, I need to query returned:
Product 2 - return the product because the table 'url' no entry for language_id = 2,
Product 3 ,
Product 4 ,
Product 99

Comment: I don't understand what your asking, in your example Product 2 is actually in table 'url' with the valid entry for the lanuage_id of 1.  Are you trying to get all the products for a specific language? or products with more than one language?